# Win32 API: ReadFile not timing out

Tags: winapi, usb, serial-communication

I'm writing some code to interface with a piece of hardware.  The hardware connects to the PC via a USB with a USB-to-Serial converter inside the device (it shows up as a COM port device in Windows).

I'm having issues with the Win32 API ReadFile system call.  I can't seem to get it to work as advertised.  I've setup the COMMTIMEOUTS structure as so:

```
COMMTIMEOUTS ct;
ct.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
ct.ReadTotalTimeoutconstant = 0;
ct.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
ct.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
ct.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;

if(SetCommTimeouts(device_id_, &ct) == 0)
{
     return ERROR; // this is never hit.
}
```

Which according to the Win32 API documentation, says:

> **ReadIntervalTimeout**
>
> The maximum time
>   allowed to elapse between the arrival
>   of two bytes on the communications
>   line, in milliseconds. During a
>   ReadFile operation, the time period
>   begins when the first byte is
>   received. If the interval between the
>   arrival of any two bytes exceeds this
>   amount, the **ReadFile** operation is
>   completed and any buffered data is
>   returned. A value of zero indicates
>   that interval time-outs are not used.
>
> A value of MAXDWORD, combined with
>   zero values for both the
>   **ReadTotalTimeoutConstant** and
>   **ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier** members,
>   specifies that the read operation is
>   to return immediately with the bytes
>   that have already been received, even
>   if no bytes have been received.

The command I'm sending is supposed to return a single byte integer.  Most of the time, the command is received by the device and it returns the appropriate value.  Sometimes, however, it doesn't seem to return a value and ReadFile() blocks until more bytes are recieved (eg. by pressing buttons on the device).  Once a button is hit, the initial integer response I was expecting is received along with the button press code.  While this isn't the behavior I'm expecting from the device itself, I'm more concerned with ReadFile() blocking when it shouldn't be, according to the MSDN documentation.  Is there a remedy for ReadFile() blocking here?

Comment: Did you check if the call to `SetCommTimeouts` is successful?

Comment: Indeed I did.  No error returned.  I even tried calling GetCommTimeouts() on the device again afterwards into a new COMMTIMEOUTS struct just to make sure the device settings were correct.

Comment: Maybe UART on USB port has no buffer - I derive that from the second paragraph of quoted documentation - something looks fishy there.  Also, ReadFile documentation doesn't say anything about returning if no data is available.  Also, it wouldn't hurt to look what's the value of MAXDWORD - or try to put 1 instead...

Comment: @Danel:  From the ReadFile() documentation:  "When reading from a communications device, the behavior of ReadFile is determined by the current communication time-out as set and retrieved by using the SetCommTimeouts and GetCommTimeouts functions. Unpredictable results can occur if you fail to set the time-out values. For more information about communication time-outs, see COMMTIMEOUTS."

Comment: Yup, that's the way the Microsoft serial port driver interprets it.  The frikkin moron that is writing all those USB serial port emulators that everybody bought a license to for a *really* reasonable price hasn't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh!  Turns out ReadFile blocking was just a symptom, not the problem.  The hardware device in question only has a 4MHz processor in it.  Splitting up the 3 character command written to the device and sending them individually with a 1ms pause between characters fixes the issue.